# Asynctask is not functioning

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast

I am trying to extract data from [here](http://researchweb.iiit.ac.in/%7Ename.jain/data). I want to extract all the data and print it on the log cat, I'm using AsyncTask to fetch the data but the data is not being fetched.

The toast is not showing up and also the Log Cat window is not printing out anything.

Here's my code :

```
package com.example.name.bill;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        new MyTask();
    }

    private void readStream(InputStream in)
    {
        Log.e("TAG", in.toString());
    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<URL , Integer, JSONObject>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... s) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://researchweb.iiit.ac.in/~name.jain/data");
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Hello Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                readStream(in);
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me where am I going wrong.

Note: The data provided in the link is not confidential, it's just for learning purpose.

UPD1:

Log Cat:

`11-06 17:12:03.544 5433-5433/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni`

`11-06 17:12:04.008 5433-5477/com.example.name.bill D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true`

`11-06 17:12:04.026 5433-5433/com.example.name.bill D/Atlas: Validating map...`

`11-06 17:12:04.154 5433-5477/com.example.name.bill I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1__release_AU ()`

`11-06 17:12:04.154 5433-5477/com.example.name.bill I/Adreno-EGL: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03`

`11-06 17:12:04.154 5433-5477/com.example.name.bill I/Adreno-EGL: Build Date: 10/28/14 Tue`

`11-06 17:12:04.154 5433-5477/com.example.name.bill I/Adreno-EGL: Local Branch:`

`11-06 17:12:04.154 5433-5477/com.example.name.bill I/Adreno-EGL: Remote Branch: quic/l_LNX.LA.3.6`

`11-06 17:12:04.154 5433-5477/com.example.name.bill I/Adreno-EGL: Local Patches: NONE`

`11-06 17:12:04.154 5433-5477/com.example.name.bill I/Adreno-EGL: Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.04.04.02.162.107 + cb93e16 + f50fe49 + d7c18e6 + 5b9a565 + 0f3a25d + 607156e + 75511aa + e4d16c0 + 686f3eb + 211a271 + dd281ee +  NOTHING`

`11-06 17:12:04.157 5433-5477/com.example.name.bill I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4`

`11-06 17:12:04.194 5433-5477/com.example.name.bill D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0`

`11-06 17:12:08.274 5433-5684/com.example.name.bill E/TAG: java.io.BufferedInputStream@2ad62e1f`

`11-06 17:12:36.697 5433-5443/com.example.name.bill W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.339ms`

Comment: remove  `Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Hello Lashit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` from `InBackground(....)`

Comment: Even if I remove that the logcat is not printing out the data

Comment: have you added the internet permission in manifest..?

Comment: post the logcat here...

Comment: boss can you give full logcat...??

Comment: App is running smoothly now but the data is not being rendered in Upadated the LogCat.

Comment: @sourabhbans This is the full error LogCat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do like

```
new MyTask().execute();
```

and also remove

```
Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Hello Lashit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

from `InBackground(....)`

Comment: The app stopped running as soon as I did that

Comment: @udhy learn [How to used AsyncTask?](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.VjyG01R97IU)

Comment: @udhy Check your Argument also wrong. you should pass the argument

Comment: Actually I was passing the url earlier but then the InBackground takes it in as URL... and the urlConnection was throwing in an error.

Answer (score 1):

Use it.. I have tested with your URL...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new TheTask().execute("http://researchweb.iiit.ac.in/~lashit.jain/data");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {

            ProgressDialog pd=null;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pd.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                 try
                    {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        if(entity != null){
                            return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                        }
                        else{
                            return "No string.";
                        }
                     }
                     catch(Exception e){
                         return "Network problem";
                     }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Log.e("result",result);

                if(pd!=null) pd.dismiss();
            }




        }
}
```

Comment: I am working on SDK Version 23 and I won't use apache org anymore as use of them is deprecated in this version.